# When can "lose to"' be used instead of ''lose by''?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Could someone explain me why the following phrase uses the bolded *to* instead of (to my opinion) *by*? (This phrase has been extracted from a newspaper article.)

> Mr Bersani’s PD has been leading in the polls ever since the election was called but, thanks in part to a proliferation of parties, with a share of the vote that is lower than when it lost **to** Mr Berlusconi five years ago.

Comment: This could work as a question for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but here on ELU it is plain off-topic. No native speaker would ever use "lose by" to mean "lose to", or vice versa. They just mean entirely different things.

Answer (score 3):

You're incorrect, *by* could not be used here, so this isn't a case of being allowed to use *to* instead of *by*.

The parties are the subject and agents ("doers") of *lost*, it is they who did the losing. Berlusconi is who they lost *to*. He is the prepositional object of the clause.

We could use *by* if we rephrase it so that we use a verb passively, and the subject becomes the patient ("done to") and the object (Berlusconi) becomes the agent:

> ...with a share of the vote that is lower than when it was beaten by Mr Berlusconi...